# The function $\frac1x$ is an homeomorphism

Tags: general-topology, analysis, continuity

I have the function $f:(0,+\infty)\rightarrow (0,+\infty)$ defined by $f(x)=\frac1x$

I want to prove that $f$ is an homeomorphism.

So I have that $f$ is surjective or onto by definition and that $f$ strictly decreasing so $f$ is bijective.

I must prove that $f$ and $f^{-1}$ are continuous. I know that if $f$ is strictly decreasing then $f^{-1}$ is strictly decreasing, so my idea is to prove that if $f$ is onto and strictly decreasing then $f$ is continuous.

To see the continuity of $f$ I let $\varepsilon>0$ and I have the estimate

$|f(x)-f(x_0)|=\displaystyle\frac{|x_0-x|}{x x_0}<\varepsilon$ and here I stop I don't know how to find $\delta$.

Help me please

Thank you.

Comment: Maybe it is also interesting to notice that here $f=f^{-1}$.

Comment: @MartinSleziak why $f=f^{-1}$ please how to notice this ?

Comment: If $y=f(x)$, i.e. $y=\frac1x$, then we easily get $x=\frac1y$, i.e., $x=f(y)$. We can also see this from the graph, since the graph of $y=\frac1x$ is symmetric w.r.t. the axis of the first quadrant.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of going to epsilon/deltas,  if you're allowed to use very basic theorems, you have that the ratio of two continuous functions is continuous as long as the denominator is nonzero, and the functions $g(x)=1$ and $h(x)=x$ are continuous, and h(x) is nonzero in your domain,  hence $f(x)=\frac 1 x$ is continuous on $(0,\infty )$.

You get $f^{-1}$ is continuous because f is its own inverse.

Comment: Thank you, but if i don't want to use the surjectivity of $f$ how to do in general when i found $|f(x)-f(x_0)|\leq\displaystyle\frac{|x_0-x|}{x_0x}$  how to choose $\delta$ please

Answer (score 0):

Because $f$ is onto, there must be some $x_1$ taking the value $f(x_0)+\epsilon$, i.e.,
$$f(x_1)-f(x_0)=\epsilon.$$
Similarly, there must be some $x_2$ taking the value $f(x_0)-\epsilon$, i.e., 
$$f(x_2)-f(x_0)=-\epsilon.$$
Now let $$\delta=max(x_0-x_1,x_2-x_0),$$
then whenever $\mid x-x_0\mid <\delta$ we have 
$$x\in \left(x_1,x_2\right)$$
and thus, because $f$ is strictly decreasing,
$$f(x_1)>f(x)>f(x_2).$$
This implies easily
$$\mid f(x)-f(x_0)\mid <max(\mid f(x_1)-f(x_0)\mid,\mid f(x_2)-f(x_0)\mid)=\epsilon.$$

Comment: Thank you, but if i don't want to use the surjectivity of $f$ how to do in general when i found $|f(x)-f(x_0)|\leq\displaystyle\frac{|x_0-x|}{x_0x}$ how to choose $\delta$ please

Comment: Well, after $\mid f(x)-f(x_0)\mid=\mid \frac{1}{x}-\frac{1}{x_0}\mid$ in principle this means just solving the inequalities $\frac{1}{\frac{1}{x_0}-\epsilon}>x>\frac{1}{\frac{1}{x_0}+\epsilon}$ and plugging $x=x_0\pm\delta$ you get $\delta<\frac{1}{\frac{1}{x_0}+\epsilon}-x_0$.

Comment: You will not be able to find some $\delta$ independent of $x_0$ because $f(x)=\frac{1}{x}$ is not uniformly continuous.